# Convert URL to SEO Friendly

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

I have a few questions.
In my website, I have, for example, a link like this:

> localhost/ecom/index.php?pages=1&title=quem-somos

The index file checks the `GET['pages']` for the id, and assign two variables based on info from the db: `$static_id`, and `$static_title`.

How do I configure the .htaccess to "convert" this link to this:

> localhost/ecom/quem-somos

And when the .htaccess is written, my href should be like this:

> localhost/ecom/quem-somos

or, should be like this:

> localhost/ecom/index.php?pages=1&title=quem-somos

and the url is converted to the SEO friendly one?

Sorry if there's some stupid questions here, I've read a few blog posts but still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this one in your /ecom/ dir

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /ecom/

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(css|js|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|bmp)$
  RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?$ index.php?title=$1&pages=$2 [L,B,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Maybe **RewriteBase** is no need, based on your serve configuration, so if some remove.

Or put this one variatn to your root dir

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(css|js|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|bmp)$
  RewriteRule ^ecom\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?$ /ecom/index.php?title=$1&pages=$2 [L,B,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I'm prefer first one.
Your urls must be like http://localhost/ecom/some-title/1/
Notice **/1/** on the end, it need to pass pages variable

Comment: Thank you. At least, something is working now, with the first code you posted. But now when I open the page, the link http://localhost/ecom/quem-somos/1/, the page don't have any styles, as if there's no css file.

Comment: Check your css file path, usual error if you used relative path like "../style.css" use absolute path like "/style.css" or like "/ecom/style.css" based on where you stored style, because for browser path is "/ecom/some-title/1/" and if your css is relative it seeks in wrong place